# Botón para ejecutar archivo con parámetro sin formulario

Tags: html

Tengo el presente código, pero al no utilizar el formulario, cómo puedo ejecutar el index.php con el parámetro descargarcsv (que es otro archivo php) solo con dar click al botón?

```
<form name="descargar" class="form-horizontal" action="index.php?descargarcsv" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Descargar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacer esto. ¿Tienes alguna restricción en cómo hacerlo?¿puedes usar JavaScript?¿has intentado algo y te falló?

Comment: Yo la verdad no entendí que quieres lograr, quieres ejecutar index.php sin que se envíe el formulario??

Comment: Quiero ejecutar descargarcsv.php a través de index.php (que es mi despachador).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente utilicé el formulario. 
Y el archivo **descargarcsv.php** al descargar el archivo `csv` deja la ventana abierta. Así que le agregué un botón **Cerrar**. 
Y listo.
Yo quería que muestre otro mensaje, pero creo que no es necesario.

Answer (score -1):

```
action="index.php?accion=descargarcsv"

if(isset($_POST[accion])){
    // código
}else{
    // código
}
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, ya que requeriría un formulario que es lo que el usuario pone que no quiere usar (en el título)